# Name of systemd service to wait for network start on boot?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, boot, systemd

I disabled it and want to reenable it using

systemctl enable

but can't find the name anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's a separate unit for each main network service:

- For systemd-networkd, `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`
- For NetworkManager, `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`
- For connman, `connman-wait-online.service`
- For Debian's ifupdown, `ifupdown-wait-online.service`

Enable the one your system needs.

There is also a master unit, `network-online.target`. You cannot (or at least, should not) enable this unit globally. Only individual services which *need* immediate network access will list it as a dependency, and in turn the .target will list one of the above services as a dependency.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty sure it was the second one.